# I am trying to run cmu sphinx4 by calling it in android but there is a file not found exception for means file

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

[image]
This is th output after running android application for speech input.
File not found exception for means in acoustic model path

Comment: Try putting the file in `raw` folder rather than `assets` folder

Comment: Add code snippet as well full error log

Comment: Thank you @Lucifer

Comment: @RomaJain, putting file in `raw` folder worked for you ?